# image border on text using CSS?

Tags: html, text, css

I've seen codes using text-shadow to make the text have a plain color outline, like this post describes: [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border) but I would like to use an image for the border. When I add

```
border-image: url (  );
```

to this code:

```
.mytext {
background: url( ); 
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
-webkit-background-clip: text; 
}
```

it adds an image border around the entire piece of text, instead of one that contours to the letters. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: what exactly do you need can you post here the screenshot of your expected result..........

Comment: yes, this kind of effect- I've taken a screenshot, but the silver outline is actually a glitter gif.http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_maikeohPOg1r49shn.gif

Answer (score 0):

shadow as like this and give to multiple border in single div

```
.imgtag{
background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1e8f64b9e6549d2664907753f7df05e3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat 0 0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid 10px red;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 4px green, 0 0 0 10px yellow , 0 0 0 15px pink , 0 0 0 20px black ;
  margin:100px;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/XD66zpv8)***

Comment: thanks for you reply! I'm not looking to format the border of a box around the text, but of the text itself, resulting in something like this which I also pasted after a comment on the original question: http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_maikeohPOg1r49shn.gif