# CSS text-border?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

Is it possible to set a '*text-border*' with CSS?

Best would be to have multiple borders? something like on the image

[image]

Comment: I would look into fonts like http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 21):

Well you could try a font shadow.  Something with multiple borders might have to be done with an image though.

```
           text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
```

Comment: this will not do the efect from the image.
I want to make a consistent line around the letter, but with a little spacing from the letter

Comment: I luv you @AgnosticDev. You really saved a lot of my time

Comment: Glad I could help out @Ben Lind

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to take a look at `CSS text-shadow`

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textshadow.html

You cannot achieve multiple borders but you can do some amazing things with it:

http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects

(i love that neon effect :)

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks for the link! The "anaglyphic" effect is my favorite.

Answer (score -1):

You could simulate stroked text as in this previous answer:-

[Outline effect to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text)