# How to create the Super Saiyan effect in CSS / JS ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I was a child, I used to read all Dragon Ball manga books.

The Super Saiyan effect (surrounding aura and lightning) is really cool!

Now I have an event page which lists all upcoming events in cards and it looks like this:

[image]

And here is the code

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 event">
        <div class="row hidden-xs icon">
            <div class="title">16 Apr</div>
            <div class="event-time"><i>8:00PM</i></div>
            <div class="sub-title">Registration Opens 14 Apr</div>
        </div>

    <div class="row hidden-xs sub-icon">
        <div><span>LRC Thursday Night Run test long long</span></div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row visible-xs-inline-block hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm event-sm">
        <div class="col-xs-4 event-left">
            <div class="event-day">16</div>
            <div class="event-month">apr</div>
            <div class="event-time"><i>8:00PM</i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 event-right">
            <div class="event-notice">Registration Opens 14 Apr</div>
            <div class="event-title">LRC Night Run</div>
            <div class="event-slogan">Come run with us</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One of them is a special event.

So here is what I want:

**I want this special event being surrounded by the "Super Saiyan" effect!**

So it will look like this one:

[image]
(sorry the Saiyan isn't drawn beautifully, but the effect is well addressed)

So there will be many lightning strikes and flames around this event card, and they are flowing!

Sorry, I cannot come up with any css code for this one as I am not even sure that whether it can be done by css or not.

Is it possible?

---

**Update**

If this is impossible, how about the **static** lightning and flames(KI)? And it has to be responsive.

---

**Update 2**

Also, this page is responsive, and it would be terrible if the flame and lightning were mis-placed when the page got resized.
So here is how it looks like on a smaller screen

[image]

---

**Update 3**

Here is my css code for event card:

```
.event {
    margin:10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon {
    background: #545454 url(../Content/img/event-icon.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.title{
  font-weight: 700;
  color:#6c6c6c;
  font-size: 67px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);

}

.sub-title{
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  color:#87e300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20 675334', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.event-time{
  color:orange;
  font-size:25px;
}


.sub-icon {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-around;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20 675334', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

    .sub-icon span {
        display: inline-block;
        -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
        -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color:black;
    }

.sub-icon div{
  margin-top : 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}


.event-day{
  font-size:24px;
  line-height:0.85;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  color: #6c6c6c;
}
.event-month{
  color: #cccbcb;
  font-size: 42px;
}


.event-time{
  color:orange;
  font-size:25px;
}


.event-notice {
    color: #87e300;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:600;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: .95;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20 675334', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.event-title{
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:800;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'TradeGothicW01-BoldCn20 675334', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.event-slogan{
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:600;
  color: #999;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .event-sm {
        display: flex !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants moving flames and moving lightning around its object, if I've got it right. This is probably an SVG use-case, but it needs a lot of work, and BTW I doubt the result will be satisfying: a rectangle is not a sayan. A super-rectangle won't be as good as a super-sayan, as a consequence

Comment: SVG and jQuery can get you what you are looking for... For reference check this. http://codepen.io/dghez/pen/jyhHt

Comment: By the way, the lightning effect is here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/xq2cpb8s

Comment: To be fair, this question seems to have attracted large popularity and people seem to think of this as a challenge, and I'm personally curious to see more possible answers.

Comment: @AndreaLigios good find!

Comment: Without you poasting your css i can make my solution responsive. You seem to have a  @media class defined and resize your elements there after! Your html is not so useful if you don't post your css code.

Comment: Until this won't be reopen (if ever), I'll post the demo that I did for the lulz and wanted to post as an answer (along with the explanation): http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/29mp8vuz/

Comment: @AndreaLigios Cool! Post reopened :)

Answer (score 15):

## SVG

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/poi33/pen/aOBNop)**

I am a bit unsure if you wanted the yellow KI glow or the lighting so i went for the lighting effect.

I reused a simple <svg> shape with the **<use>** element.

The lighting shape is taken from Gohan.
The top left lighting. [image: Pic]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.calander {} .calander h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.calander .event-grid {
  margin: 0 5%;
}
.event-grid .event {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #4c4c4c 0%, #212121 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #4c4c4c), color-stop(100%, #212121));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #4c4c4c 0%, #212121 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #4c4c4c 0%, #212121 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #4c4c4c 0%, #212121 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #4c4c4c 0%, #212121 100%);
}
.event .date {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #222;
}
.event .time {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #dd8834;
}
.event .note {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: LawnGreen;
}
.event .bottom-reg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.event .bottom-reg p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.event .bottom-reg input {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #55f;
  border: 1px solid #99f;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.test {
  display: none;
}
.spesial {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section class="calander">
    <h2>UPCOMING EVENTS</h2>
    <div class="event-grid">
      <div class="event">
        <h1 class="date">16 APR</h1>
        <span class="time">8:00 PM</span>
        <br>
        <span class="note">registration</span>
        <div class="bottom-reg">
          <p>LRC</p>
          <input placeholder="REGISTER"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event">
        <h1 class="date">19 APR</h1>
        <span class="time">10:00 PM</span>
        <br>
        <span class="note">registration</span>
        <div class="bottom-reg">
          <p>LRC</p>
          <input placeholder="REGISTER"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="spesial">
          <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
            <use x="40" y="100" transform="scale(0.5) rotate(20)" xlink:href="#light" />
            <use x="150" y="-790" transform="scale(0.2) rotate(90)" xlink:href="#light" />
            <use x="0" y="200" transform="scale(0.35) rotate(-45)" xlink:href="#light" />
            <use x="-240" y="390" transform="scale(0.5) rotate(-70)" xlink:href="#light" />
            <use x="300" y="-90" transform="scale(0.4) rotate(90)" xlink:href="#light" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event">
        <h1 class="date">23 APR</h1>
        <span class="time">8:00 PM</span>
        <br>
        <span class="note">registation</span>
        <div class="bottom-reg">
          <p>LRC</p>
          <input placeholder="REGISTER" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <svg class="test" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path fill="#ddf" stroke="#ddf" id="light" d="m 0,0 c 6.24111,-8.9445 10.61204,-23.77912 17.97353,-53.80856 l 29.7995,-5.55584 35.35534,41.92133 c -1.95372,12.45653 45.89675,34.80534 61.61931,34.34518 -17.63651,5.49982 -9.56977,24.91725 2.52538,36.87057 C 139.10793,46.26094 131.45087,39.06432 122.46831,22.22336 118.45247,16.48431 87.40919,-0.96167 83.63345,0.73967 c -9.2424,4.06941 -3.52888,14.963 -1.51523,18.60117 -4.31715,4.656 -7.89706,8.06774 -8.43836,13.6677 0.0873,-12.34933 1.5179,-42.45863 -5.49456,-26.14667 L 65.95578,-14.91769 C 61.11992,-21.99984 48.27857,-50.5446 47.89033,-37.93673 46.10689,-46.50735 39.22534,-49.00909 35.6512,-48.25273 17.657,-46.88454 17.9011,-38.9303 16.45831,-31.58521 7.76504,-6.22367 6.56293,-8.29891 0,0 Z"
      />
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent~! Hi Perijn, yes~! I want both lightning and the gold flames(KI). could  you please add it as well? thanks~!!!!

Answer (score 14):

This might not be the best way, but a quick way could be to download an animated gif of super saiyan, make it transparent, edit the character out, then use css to overlay the image on your event.

[image: Super Saiyan gif]

With better photo editing software this could probably look a lot better, but this only took me about 5 minutes.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpLMGr

```
<div class="event">
    <img id="saiyan" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFoa1.gif" />
    <h1 class="date">19 APR</h1>
    <span class="time">10:00 PM</span>
    <br>
    <span class="note">registration</span>
    <div class="bottom-reg">
      <p>LRC</p>
      <input placeholder="REGISTER"></input>
    </div>
  </div>

<style>
    #saiyan {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 160%;
      height: 100%;
      left: -30%;
      top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

I just absolutely position the image over the rest of the event object, and have its width and height dependent on the event `div`.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. Could you try it  out and edit this question? Just apply the png image to a div overlapping the middle event. :) Would like to see it :P

Comment: good idea, but how to make the flame and lightning fit the size of my event card could be hard as when the page got resized, how to calculate the size and position of the gif? thanks

Comment: You could set the width and height of the image as a percent of a wrapper div. It might make the image distort a bit though

Comment: add the fiddle to your answer and explain your code :D I can see its really simple

Comment: I love your class names :)

Comment: wow @mpadittech that's really impressive and it's changing shapes!!!! What software do you use to make the flames and lightning? As I want to make the flames more fit to the size and shape of my event card, thinner and a little bit transparent, so it will look like flowing around the card and the lightning appearing and disappearing on the card. Btw, I agree with Persijn, I love your class name :)

Comment: I just downloaded this gif here: http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view4/4644630/gohan-super-saiyan-o.gif  then used this tool to split it into different frames: http://gifmaker.me/exploder/  then used paint.net to make each frame transparent and remove gohan (in this step you could change the transparency of the flames if you wnated) and then use this tool to combine the frames back into an animated gif: http://gifmaker.me/     As for the flame size, you could change the width and height percentages if you wanted them to change proportionally, but beyond that you would have to pick a different gif

Comment: wow, that's a very detailed explanation! I want the inner shape of the KI become rectangle, not sure if it's possible by using the tools you mentioned. Anyway, this can be and should be moved into your post and can be a part of your answer and it's very helpful! Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

> <sub>**Disclaimer**: this code is for the lulz.</sub>

Moved by curiosity, I've created a small example you might like:

[image]

### [Running demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/29mp8vuz/)

---

#### Lightning effect

I've used the *HTML5 Canvas Lightning* from [this fiddle](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xq2cpb8s), that is itself a fork of [akm2's *Lightning Points (Lightning 2)*](http://jsdo.it/akm2/amk0); the canvas is then placed under a div with `0.99` of `opacity`, `20px` oversized on each side, to give [the effect of surrounding](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/29mp8vuz/3) the boundaries, but only of few pixels.

#### Fire effect

The fire effect in CSS is easily achievable with the `text-shadow` property; I've taken parts of [this](http://codepen.io/atnyman/pen/cgGuL/) but it is the same code I've seen dozens of time in many articles / fiddles, probably the first one ever is [the one in the second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553212/1654265).

Since this applies only to text and not, for example, to divs, I've used the `content` attribute of the `:before` pseudo-element of the `.sayan` div to create a huge text composed by symbols (for a romantic reason, I've used the Go (悟) kanji from Goku (悟空), but the important is that it is not a recognizable alphabetic  character, or goodbye *aura effect*... try it by yourself with `content: 'a';`), and I've put it between the canvas and the div with a negative `z-index`.

This is just an experiment for fun, not production code nor responsive stuff as asked in the question (even though if you resize the page, the divs move and the sayan div will retain its capabilities); my attempt to answer the question:

> is it possible to do it, and how ?

, that I hope you liked.

If you want to transform it to something more serious, there is a lot of work to do (first of all, alter the script to make some dots moving *only* along the sides, to prevent having all of them inside the square), but I still suggest you to use a transparent animated PNG, or however something easier and less CPU-killer than this, declaratively made for the sake of the lulz ;)

Comment: Hi Andrea, it's amazing! Thank you for your attempt to solve this challenge! I highly appreciate your work and efforts to make it into this stage. It looks great. Only a few things to be changed: 1. the fire seems have outer shape which is a rectangle. so if it could be made to something which is shapeless yet still burning around the event card, that would be superb! 2. Lightning is cool! but yes, I agree with what you mentioned in your post. 3. Responsiveness. Beside these 3, I think it's almost there!!! Great work!! Hopefully, we could see someone to make it happen!

Comment: Yes, the shape is the underlying canvas. I guess it can be adjusted by tweaking the javascript. Otherwise, you can reduce the size of the flames, to prevent to enlighten the outer zone (and hence showing the boundaries)