# 'Text Border' Decoration in CSS

Tags: css, text, styling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

When I'm in Photoshop, it's easy for me to type a text and then apply white border to the 'text' and then apply shadow into it.
[image]

But when I'm in HTML, I need a `<div>`, `<p>` or `<span>` or any tag like this to write a text. Then to decorate the text like this, we especially apply the decoration to the tag, NOT TO THE TEXT (or content) of the tag. Suppose:

```
<span id="decor">Text</span>
```

Then we do CSS like:

```
#decor{color: #9E0B0E; border: 5px solid #FFF; box-shadow: 3px 0 2px #CCC;}
```

But what it does is to style the span, not the content of the span tag (for here: 'Text').

So, my question is:

- **HOW TO STYLE TEXT LIKE THIS USING `CSS`?**

#### SECOND EDIT

After some comments and replies, PLEASE CONSIDER THAT, The `text-shadow` property is doing only one job, whether a white border or a grey shadow, but I want 'em BOTH.

Comment: Just like you show. That's it.

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's a bit different issue. I mentioned about it in Second Edit section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<p class="decor">Text</p>
```

and then

```
p.decor{
color: #9E0B0E; 
text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white; 
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, the `text-shadow` thing is not doing what exactly I's looking for, but doing thing partially. It's just making the white border to the text (using shadow), but I want a border along with a grey shadow, like the image above. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Look at [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/stroke.html)
and then add text shadow.

Comment: You can extend the text-shadow property with additional shadows: `text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white, 4px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not any easy way to do this and support multiple browsers.  Webkit supports the css tag -webkit-text-stroke but that leaves out Firefox and IE (amongst others)

Example:

```
p {
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black
}
```