# How it's possible to add some borders to the text?

Tags: css, text, border

I'm working with some text with `color:black;` and I need to add some borders with colour yellow to each letter.I'm tried to add some border effect using **text shadow** but which didn't help me(which didn't produce an absolute border effect).I searched for a long time,but i didn't get a better solution.can anyone help to add some borders to text?

```
<p> some text here </p>
p{
color:black;
font-size:2rem;
text-border:3px #000;/*i need to achieve this*/
}
```

I'm added an image to clarify my problem(here each text have a color:sky-blue,and it's border have a color:blue;)

[image]

as mention above I know it's possible by using text-shadow,but when use `text-shadow` we can't increase the width of the border,when we try to increase it's border-width the opacity will narrow down.that is why I'm asking for a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to give border to text using two options: either using text-shadow or text-fill-color and text-stroke-color

For more reference: Check out this: [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

Comment: You should not post a link to an answer which is a duplicate, you flag the question.

Comment: okay. I will flag as duplicate next time onwards