# CSS Text Border With Padding

Tags: html, css

I have read about text borders here:

[CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

In that post, they are using font-shadow to make the border, but I cannot remove the shadow colour, and I only need the border because I need to  show a picture behind the space between the text and the border and create some space between the text and the border.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Easter Egg !]

This is what I have done so far (it is incorrect because the border is connected with the text):

```html
<style>
h1 {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
</style>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Sorry if you cannot understand me, what I mean is that **I need a border around the text with transparent space**, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

I also cannot use image as replacement of text .

Comment: Do you mean that you want a transparent border around the letters?

Comment: no , i want to show the border but make space between text and the border transparent

Comment: Have you tried svg?

Comment: @NathanielFlick , i need to create it with css not picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible. Especially the requirement of making an outer border of transparency. While `box-shadow` has an inset property, `text-shadow` does not. Background clip can create some interesting effects in conjunction with `text-shadow` but nothing like what you're looking for.

```css
span{font-size: 300px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
background-color: #ed5c65;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span>M</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ttgv3ng/

Comment: @NikunjSardhara you're doubling the text and markup. I don't think that's acceptable for a minor css effect. Although, it's up to OP to decide what works for him.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to manipulate css in a correct way.

I have prepared a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvHJq/1540/).

You're welcome.

```css
#text{
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:100;
  font-family:arial;  
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    left:4px;
    top:7px;
}
#borders{
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:arial;
  color:white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
   }
```

```html
<div id="text">M</div><div id="borders">M</div>
```

Comment: as the picture : http://i.imgur.com/4dC2GiG.png , the word M is outside the border shaped like M , and i need the word M is inside the border shaped like M

Comment: Could you try in firefox?

Comment: The solution you are asking cannot be done in one element and YOU need to adapt it to all devices my modifying it, the solution which i gave you is a POC which you should appreciate, otherwise consider using canvas or svg

Answer (score -1):

Check This!

```css
h1 {
 font-size:80px;
  /* WebKit (Safari/Chrome) Only */
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
  
  /* If we weren't using text-shadow, we'd set a fallback color
     and use this to set color instead
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white; */
    color: white;
  
  text-shadow:
    3px 3px 0 #000,
    /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera
       and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
   -1px  1px 0 #000,
    1px  1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>M O H A N</h1>
```

Comment: almost like what i try to achieve , but still it's only " almost " , i will find another answer first before think about this

Comment: i also need the text anyway not just the border