# how to get this kind of stroke and shadow using css

Tags: html, css

I try stroke and get no result so please suggest me css for this problem. I also try shadow to text:

[image: how to get this kind of stroke in css]

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #030303;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fbf7f7;
  text-shadow: 8px -2px 0 #fff4f4,
  -4px -6px 0 #fff,
  -6px -5px 0 #fff,
  -8px 5px 0 #fffbfb;
}

/* added by Editor for demonstration purpose */
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-stroke`:

```css
body{
  background:gray;
}
p{
  font-size:38px;
  font-weight:700;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
}
```

```html
<p>Text with shadow</p>
```